# Laravel 5.8 blade, getting values from nested objects error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am getting some weird error while working with blade.

It works just like it should when getting the data inside a `dd()`, but
when calling it without a `dd()`, an error is thrown telling me that it can't find a field in my object.

In my blade file, this works just fine:

```html
{{ dd($p->components->image->lg_img) }}
```

This doesn't:

```html
<img src="{{ $p->components->image->lg_img }}" />
```

##### The error:

> Undefined property: stdClass::$image (View:
> /home/vagrant/code/xxxxxx/resources/views/resources.blade.php)

Comment: what are `$p` and `components`?

Comment: Is it in loop? If so then first loop element has it set and some other doesn't.

Comment: You can also comment out that `img` tag and use `@dump $p->components @enddump` for debugging

Comment: I found the solution, when some of the objects in the loop didn't  contain the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:
**check if the variable exists**

```
<img src="{{ !empty($p->components->image->lg_img) }}" />
```

This problem happens because some attributes might not exist.